# How clustering is used in data management?

Tags: data, management

Can anyone please tell me how is clustering is used in data management?

I was recently asked this question and was left totally stumped.

Comment: I've seen clustering used to create an index and data dictionary for data management.

Comment: Thats a really cool idea.Could you please elaborate on it.As it would really help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Too vague. Do you mean clustering like how a table is organized physically, or clustering in the machine learning sense?

Comment: Clustering in the machine learning sense

Comment: Are you sure they did not mean the other sense? This is such a vague and frankly poor question.

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate further also on what do you mean by data management.

Comment: I think clustering helps in detecting outliers in data to prevent ambiguous information/pattern extraction during machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wide open question, so I am not sure which aspects you are most interested in.  Here are some Wikipedia articles you can get started with.

[Metadata Harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_for_Metadata_Harvesting)

[Metadata Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_discovery)